# Can I dd from one opened luks container to another?

Tags: linux, encryption, dd, luks

I want to migrate my encrypted data from one drive to another. Both source and target should be encrypted. I've read in some other question, that I should create a new container, so that the superkey is not reused.

So, can I do the following? Or would it be better to mount and use something like rsync?

```
# cryptsetup open /dev/sda1 home
# cryptsetup open /dev/sdb1 home_new
# dd if=/dev/mapper/home of=/dev/mapper/home_new
```